# Recurring Noise from Water Cooling System

Tags: hardware-failure, water-cooling, silent-cooling

I have a Be Quiet - Silent Loop water cooling system that occasionally drops RPM down to 10% of typical performance. This is accompanied by a loud continuously sounding noise.

I recently refilled the water (assuming I should not empty it first) and expected the sound to subside, but it occasionally breaks down, only to recover after roughly a minute or two.

I have read that there could possibly be air trapped in the system. What can I do to remedy the situation?

Comment: 1) Please consult BeQuiet! https://www.bequiet.com/en/watercooler/silent-loop/779 so as not to void your warranty. 2) Linus Tech Tips has shown how to purge air out of a water cooler, wish I could remember which episode: https://www.youtube.com/user/LinusTechTips

Comment: @K7AAY [This one?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRKEaYMgIYk)